# List Azure NSGs on Every Azure Subnet

Tags: azure, powershell

A bit stuck on this one. Going in circles trying to get the NSG Ids listed out for each and every subnet in Azure. It's part of a security control requirement, so we need to list each subnet and then provide the NSG Id with them - to show that each subnet does in fact have an NSG associated with it.

```
$vnets = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork).Name
$nsgId = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork).Subnets.NetworkSecurityGroup.Id
$snet = (Get-Azvirtualnetwork).Subnets.Name | Out-String

foreach ($vnet in $vnets) {Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $snet -VirtualNetwork $vnets | FL Name,$nsgId}
```

This is the error I am getting. Just can't get past it.

Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig: Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSVirtualNetwork' required by parameter 'VirtualNetwork'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: Remove `.Name` from `$vnets = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork).Name`. It needs the VirtualNetwork object. You will want to get the NSGID and Subnets inside the foreach loop, as they will be different for each VNET.

Comment: Same issue with the $vnets when removing the .Name

Comment: You are passing `$vnets` to `-VirtualNetwork` and not `$vnet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$vnets = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork)

$objectArr = @()

foreach ($vnet in $vnets) {
    foreach ($subnet in $vnet.Subnets) {
        if ($subnet.NetworkSecurityGroup -ne $null) {
            $NSG = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $subnet.NetworkSecurityGroup.Id
        
            $prop = [ordered]@{
                'VNETName' = $vnet.Name
                'SubnetName' = $subnet.Name
                'NSGName' = $NSG.Name
                'Id' = $NSG.Id
            }

            $obj = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
            $objectArr += $obj
        }
        
    }
    
}

$objectArr | Select-object VNETName, SubnetName, NSGName, Id
```